# Determine the value of n_components variable in pca analysis

Tags: python, pca

Have a nice day. Please help me. I have a normalized file. This file consists of 21 numeric columns.

I will apply `pca analysis` to this file as below :

```
pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=21)
pca_output = pca.fit_transform(pca_matrix)
pca_inverse = pca.inverse_transform(pca_output)
```

As far as I understand, the value I assign to the `n_components` variable is equal to the number of columns. But what I do not understand is how do I determine the `n_components` variable.

Answer (score 1):

It is a hyperparameter and finding its optimal value depends on what you want to do with your data. Let me describe 3 possible uses:

- **Visualization**: 2 or 3 are probably the most sensible options:)
- **Compression**: Here the goal is to simply decrease the number of features without loosing too much information. You can fit all components (`n_components=None`). Then inspect the attribute `explained_variance_ratio_` and decide how many you are willing to drop. Or you can put `n_components='mle'` and let the data decide for you.
- **Preprocessing**: Here the dimensionality reduction is a first step of some pipepline (preceding regression/classification). As opposed to compression, you want to use the transformed features as input to a supervised learning algorithm. I would recommend finding the optimal n_components through a GridSearchCV over both the PCA's `n_components` and the predictive model's hyperparameters.